# Django - pythonanywhere - ProxyConnectionError

Tags: django, amazon-s3, pythonanywhere, django-storage

I deployed my Django project on [pythonanywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com).
In the project, I use `"storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"` as `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`. It connects to a cloud storage so that I can upload and save media files on there. It works fine on my local system but on pythonanywhere, it gives this error when a media file is going to be uploaded:

```
ProxyConnectionError
Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://proxy.server:3128"
```

I'm new to this and I don't know what else information is needed on this for someone to answer my question. So let me know to edit my question.

Comment: It looks like that will not work from a free account on PythonAnywhere